# FPDF / mySQL : How to overcome encoding troubles with fpdf and mysql

Tags: mysql, fpdf

To generate PDF's invoices I use `fpdf` lib and store repeating text in a `mySQL` DB.

When I store this text in a simple file I need to save it as Latin1 encoded due to the fact that `fpdf` uses Latin1/cp1252 encoding. This works so far.

But when I store it in a `mySQL` DB I get the typical `Ã¡æ—¥�` gibberish, no matter which collation I use for the text fields. In this case I set it to Latin1_general_ci. The server itself is generally set to UTF-8 Unicode.

There are several question to this issue:

1. Does ist help to set the server also to Latin1 ?
2. Does `fpdf` also render UTF-8 encoding character to overcome this issue ?
3. Can I overcome this issue with `tpdf` rather than with `fpdf` ?

Any help to find the `one and only` solution is appreciated

UPDATE :

No answer frome no one ? Gibberish seems to be a unsolvable issue .. hm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer the question myself because I found now a solution. If it is the `one and only` I doubt, but it is a solution for my approach.

Q&A

1. Q: Does ist help to set the server also to Latin1 ?
   A: It should, but I had no success at all. Still this question is open.
2. Q: Does fpdf also render UTF-8 encoding character to overcome this
   issue ?
   A: NO, not as far as I know. I spend some time to google,
   but found no hint, nor any concrete answer.
3. Q: Can I overcome this issue with `tpdf` rather than with fpdf ?
   A: YES, it works perfect. Read [here](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script92.php).